# Back to top of page link with iFrame?

Tags: html, iframe

I am trying to make a link that will take you to the top of your page when you click it. I already have a header and footer on each page. They are embedded using iFrame. Now, I am trying to put

```
<a name="top"></a>
```

on the header, and

```
<a href="#top"></a>
```

on the footer. But when I add them, nothing happens when I click on the link. I tried adding target="_top" but that just opens the footer in a new tab.

Does anybody know how I can write the html so that it will take me to the top of the current page after clicking a link in the footer?

Comment: A simple `<a href="#"></a>` should take you to the top of the page.

Answer (score 0):

Change the `<a>` in the header to `<a id="top">`

See this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/54cwezo6/).

Answer (score 0):

Apply this code on the page where header and footer both are embedded.
**[`JSFIDDLE`](https://jsfiddle.net/the_hardik_sisodia/vm7zq9ue/)**

In head section apply this script

```js
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){

//Check to see if the window is top if not then display button
$(window).scroll(function(){
 if ($(this).scrollTop() > 100) {
  $('.scrollToTop').fadeIn();
 } else {
  $('.scrollToTop').fadeOut();
 }
});

//Click event to scroll to top
$('.scrollToTop').click(function(){
 $('html, body').animate({scrollTop : 0},200);
 return false;
});

});
</script>
```

```css
.fixedscrolltotop
{
position: fixed;
bottom: 25%;
right: 0;
width: 149px;
color:black;
font-weight:bold;
text-align:center;
-webkit-box-flex:1;
}
.scrollToTop
{
width:80px; 
height:80px; 
text-align:center; 
background: whiteSmoke;
font-weight: bold;
color: #444;
text-decoration: none;
position:fixed;
bottom:60px;
right:0px;
display:none;
background: url('http://tech.firstpost.com/wp-content/uploads/up-arrow-icon.png') no-repeat;
background-size: 100% 100%;
opacity: 0.5;
-webkit-box-flex:1;
}
.scrollToTop:hover
{
text-decoration:none;
opacity: 1;
-webkit-box-flex:1;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="fixedscrolltotop">
    <a href="" class="scrollToTop" title="Back To The Top">
    </a>
</div>
```

Is this code appropriate if looking ahead for something else do let me know